# Oracle - select top transaction for each user_id

Tags: oracle, rank, rownum

I have a select statement that gets user_id and a list of transactions for the day such as this:

```
select user_id, sale_amount, date, product from transactions
```

I want to be able to select each user_id (there are many) along with their top sale_amount, date and product. If there is a tie, I want it to just select one. How is this possible? Rownum or rank seem to be close but not quite there?

Comment: Use Rank over partition by

Comment: I think that will display multiple values in the case of a tie, I just want one

Comment: Ok. Use rownum over partition by and select only rownum = 1

Comment: Doesn't that not work for multiple users? I dont think I fully understand how that can be implemented in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I m not ifo computer but this should work. Let me know
`select * from (select user_id, sale_amount, date, product,row_number() over (partition by user_id order by sales_amount desc) as maxsale from transactions) l where maxsale=1`